# Failure to match strings(Arabic) in CHAI assertion library

Tags: chai, hebrew

I have two arrays:

```
var array_one = [
    {
        "accountNo": "1",
        "id"       : 12,
        "name"     : "אוצר החייל - 14"
    },
    {
        "accountNo": "1",
        "id"       : 13,
        "name"     : "china bank"
    }
  ],

  array_two  = [
    {
        "accountNo": "1",
        "id"       : 12,
        "name"     : "אוצר החייל - 14"
    },
    {
        "accountNo": "1",
        "id"       : 13,
        "name"     : "china bank"
    }
  ];
```

Both the array's contents are same, but it fails to assert that the two array's have the same content. ie

array_one.should.be.deep.equal(array_two) returns false;

And the reason for failure being the matching of strings in Hebrew.

Cannot figure out a way to match Hebrew strings using CHAI assertion library.